# is the use of cronjobs needed for this

Tags: php, html, mysql

When it is 5p.m. I want that my website executes some **php code**. (I don’t know how to do this)
This is what it should do:
Check which contestants have subscribed in the subscribed list (I know how to do this).
Pick a random contestant to be the first, 2nd and 3rd. (I know how to do this)
Every 2 minutes, so a game takes about 20 minutes, and I want that every 2mins I can generate a random message. (I think I can do this with sleep)

What I am wondering, my server is **linux**, so I should use cronjobs I guess?
Can cronjobs do what I want/need?

I think it’s really hard to understand cronjobs.
I have looked some stuff up but I am still in the mainly in the dark.
Do I just code php and upload it to cronjobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do a little more research and then come back and ask specific questions. Cron jobs are just shell scripts run at regular intervals. There is nothing mystical about them. You could have a cron job like this: `php /blah/blah/myScript.php` and that would run a php script.

Answer (score 1):

The question is: What do you want to do exactly?

I mean, if exactly at 5pm you want to switch your website into night design, and nobody is loading your page, then nobody would notice. So these kind of tasks are better off being done when the request is executed.

On the other hand, if at 5pm you want some email to be sent out, and nobody accesses your site, no mail would be sent. This is what cronjobs are for.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how your host is setup, setting up a cronjob can be as simple as entering a time when you would like it to run (intervals or not), and selecting the script(s).

At that time, they'll run the script you set. Do abit more research into them & look into your hosting capabilities, some hosts don't offer them as standard.